# HTML: How to go to the next page coming in ascending order?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML files having numerical names in a folder named **Project** like this:

```
230512.html
230519.html
230530.html
230630.html
240120.html
```

I want to add a **"next page button"** in each file. When I click the button, the hyperlink takes me to the page that comes next in ascending order.

So, if I am in `230530.html`, clicking on the **next page button** should take me to `230630.html`.

The file names are basically dates in **YYMMDD.html** format. Dates might not be consecutive.

Any ideas, how to create such a script?

Comment: will this have a server side part too? i.e. served via a web server or without a server side part? if it has a server side part what would be the server side language?

Comment: @AtulyaJha do you have all file names in some kind of array in the javascript?? Are these lot of files?? Are these files have same number pattern ??

Comment: 1. No, there won't be any server side part. It will just be a personal folder. not to be published on the server.

Comment: 2. The file names are basically dates in YYMMDD.html format

Comment: @AtulyaJha In client side javascript, you can't access the files in the folder. So, can you take provide all file names in the javascript or not?? Is it possible?? Because if that's not possible then you need backend like node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code for you:

```
// get current filename
let currentFileName = location.pathname.split('/').pop();

  // Get the list of all HTML files in the "Project" folder
  let fileNames = [
    '230512.html',
    '230519.html',
    '230530.html',
    '230630.html',
    '240120.html'
  ];

  // Find the index of the current file in the list
  let currentIndex = fileNames.indexOf(currentFileName);

  // Calculate the index of the next file
  let nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % fileNames.length;

  // Get the name of the next file
  let nextFileName = fileNames[nextIndex];
```

nextFileName goes back to index 0 if you are at the last page.

Comment: I think this is not OP want. OP want to get all file names and then everytime, the link should have correct next page link. The order will be in ascending

Comment: In a comment above he states that he doesn't have a server. So the filename-array can not be generated dynamically. And if his array is unsorted a quick [].sort() should fix it